Emulating method dependant argument lookup in C++?
I'm designing an API for embedded programming registers, in which many functions let you choose between e.g 3 values to set certain bits to. Therefore I'd like to the function to take an enum for these values with meaningful names. But I don't see a way to avoid repeating the enum's "path", either namespace or class, when addressing the value:
USB2_OTG_FS::hostPortControl.setPortSpeed(USB2_OTG_FS::HostPortControl::PortSpeed::FullSpeed)

Ideally, I would like to be able to write
USB2_OTG_FS::hostPortControl.setPortSpeed(PortSpeed::FullSpeed)
// 'setPortSpeed' could be just 'set' with overloads

But that would require the scope the method belongs to to be automatically used by the parameter scope, a form of 'method dependant argument lookup', which isn't a C++ feature.
I was wondering how well and how such a thing could be emulated, to avoid both the user having to clutter their scope with usings, and not have verbose repetitive calls whenever these calls involve enums.
PS - underlying structure pseudocode:
namespace USB2_OTG_FS {
    class HostPortControl {
    public:
        enum class PortSpeed {
            FullSpeed = 0b01
        };

        void setPortSpeed(PortSpeed portSpeed);
    } hostPortControl;
}


using USB2_OTG_FS::HostPortControl::PortSpeed? it depend on code details which you have not shown! We are not mind readers.

This is a made up example, I thought the structure was implied clearly from the scope operator chain. But sure, just added it. I was wondering how to avoid usingusing as including a lot of these would clutter the user scope (and also, it requires extra statements from the user).

Provide a [mcve]

Adding using USB2_OTG_FS::HostPortControl::PortSpeed; in scope where shorter version should be used should do the job.

I mean, how insane do you want to be?  With enough insanity, we could do "HostPortControl::PortSpeed"_enum where we create a global static constexpr mapping from "enum name::enum value" as strings to enum values, then have a casting operator that permits conversion only to enums that match the name::value pattern as strings.  But at some point you end up doing more work than "just write a new language".

Or equally evil, we make a macro called setPortSpeed that takes the string value of its argument and the decltype of its lefhand side and does decltype(lhs)::string value of argument to reconstruct the actual enum, then passes it to the actual method.  The call might look like USB2_OTG_FS::hostPortControl->*setPortSpeed(PortSpeed::FullSpeed).

The short answer is "no, there isn't a nice way to do this in C++".  I am just saying there are not nice ways to do it.  :)

using should be best shot without tinkering. Rest of them are not simple or you need to handle them yourself.

The reason I want to avoid using is that in a real scenario, there would be several e.g PortSpeed enums with different values, that would each make sense only when writing to given bits of a given register.

@MarekR What are you talking about? In what way does it depend on code that wasn’t shown? Also, “Adding using … should be used” how hard is it to read the question!! The OP explicitly says that they’re asking to see if there’s a way to avoid countless usings cluttering up caller code. The OP clearly already considered using and your comment isn’t adding anything.

@user12002570 MCVE of what exactly? What did you want a “verifiable” example of? The original post contains the function in question, no? The link you sent begins with “when debugging” and this question isn’t about debugging anything.

@Kröw note I've posted that comment before en edit. With extra information it is clear my solution must be tweaked.

@MarekR I checked the edit history and still did not see any reason...

Since your enum class is enclosed inside a class, this doesn't solve the problem (note that before an edit this was not clear):
using USB2_OTG_FS::HostPortControl::PortSpeed;

But small tweak to this solution and it works as desired:
void test(USB2_OTG_FS::HostPortControl& a, USB2_OTG_FS::HostPortControl& b)
{
    using PortSpeed = USB2_OTG_FS::HostPortControl::PortSpeed;

    a.setPortSpeed(PortSpeed::FullSpeed);
    b.setPortSpeed(PortSpeed::FullSpeed);
    USB2_OTG_FS::hostPortControl.setPortSpeed(PortSpeed::FullSpeed);
}

Note this is placed in the scope of a function, so this impacts only this function not the whole code.
And since C++20 you can push this even further with using enum:
void test(USB2_OTG_FS::HostPortControl& a, USB2_OTG_FS::HostPortControl& b)
{
    using enum USB2_OTG_FS::HostPortControl::PortSpeed;

    a.setPortSpeed(FullSpeed);
    b.setPortSpeed(FullSpeed);
    USB2_OTG_FS::hostPortControl.setPortSpeed(FullSpeed);
}

